# How would I do the mysql timestamps in php?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

Ok so I have a mysql database and I need an updated_at field and a created_at field like ruby on rails has by default. I was thinking of using a timestamp for the updated field and a datetime for a created at field. I was reading [this](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql) article to help me choose but i still dont know if there is a standard that is followed that will either do this automatically with automatically or with little extra code...any ideas on this

Comment: Good solid question, +1 Buddy.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice would be to use UNIX Timestamps on both.

To have UNIX timestamp in PHP, use the

```
time();
```

function, and to have it in MySQL use the

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

function. PHP can simply convert UNIX timestamps to any formatted date string using

```
Date();
```

function. And you can also make calculations with that.

Answer (score 1):

Well the code from php will only provide you with your time as your computer see's it. Where mysql it has the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it entirely in your database management system. For example, MySQL has functions to use the current date or time: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Example: `insert into a (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: You can also use MySQL's `NOW()`.

Comment: Nice I like that @ceejayoz +1

Answer (score 1):

You are on track with using TIMESTAMP for your updated field which provides the functionality you are looking for. To keep your date format consistent, I would then use DATETIME for your created field and use `now()` on insert.

I prefer UNIX timestamps, but then you have to code for the updated_at field.